# FIFO Cpu scheduling in python where Process ID, Arrival Time, Instruction Load gets collected from a xlsx worksheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I want to create a Fifo Cpu Scheduling simulator in python 3 where I want to get the Process ID, Arrival Time, Instruction Load from an excel worksheet. I'll just put this line to run the code:

```
schedule_sheet=load workbook(filename='cpu-scheduling.xlsx')
```

Now my code is running the FIFO where I am giving the details inside the program but, I am unable to fetch from the excel sheet & send that to my program.
my code is:

```py
def findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt):


    wt[0] = 0


    for i in range(1, n ):
        wt[i] = bt[i - 1] + wt[i - 1]


def findTurnAroundTime(processes, n,
                    bt, wt, tat):


    for i in range(n):
        tat[i] = bt[i] + wt[i]


def findavgTime( processes, n, bt):

    wt = [0] * n
    tat = [0] * n
    total_wt = 0
    total_tat = 0


    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt)


    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n,
                    bt, wt, tat)


    print( "Processes Burst time " +
                " Waiting time " +
                " Turn around time")


    for i in range(n):
    
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i]
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i]
        print(" " + str(i + 1) + "\t\t" +
                    str(bt[i]) + "\t " +
                    str(wt[i]) + "\t\t " +
                    str(tat[i]))

    print( "Average waiting time = "+
                str(total_wt / n))
    print("Average turn around time = "+
                    str(total_tat / n))


if __name__ =="__main__":
    

    processes = [ 1, 2, 3]
    n = len(processes)


    burst_time = [10, 5, 8]

    findavgTime(processes, n, burst_time)
```

How I can do that from the Excel sheet please help me.

This is sample picture how the excelsheet would be:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the line `schedule_sheet=load workbook(filename='cpu-scheduling.xlsx')` in your program?

Comment: I want to fetch those data about the processes & use them in the program

Comment: Yes, why don't you do it?

Comment: That's the help I need

Answer (score 0):

You've got your variable pointing to the Excel sheet with the data. You just need to put that variable in the `__main__` function and run the code, as follows:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    
    # Add these below lines of code to read data from the Excel file
    schedule_sheet=load_workbook(filename='cpu-scheduling.xlsx')
    sheets = schedule_sheet.sheetnames
    
    # To work with the first sheet (by name)
    ws = schedule_sheet[sheets[0]]
    
    processes = [ 1, 2, 3]
    n = len(processes)
    burst_time = [10, 5, 8]
    findavgTime(processes, n, burst_time)
```

Output produces:

```
Processes Burst time  Waiting time  Turn around time
 1              10       0               10
 2              5        10              15
 3              8        15              23
Average waiting time = 8.333333333333334
Average turn around time = 16.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I need to fetch the values from excel sheet to the program, where Processes= Process ID, BUrst Time= Instruction Count & also need to use the Arriaval Time

Comment: `print(*ws.values)` will give you all the data from the sheet. Then use those values in your calculations.